# react-native-maps showsUserLocation error

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

[image]

Hi, I have this problem when running react native maps page. It was working yesterday, but when i reran the project today, it outputted the error. When i opened backups of this project last week and 2 weeks ago, it is giving this same error. This error is only happening for android. For iOS, it is working well.
Please Help, Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. @Suvin Kollabathula were you able to solve it?

Comment: I'm also running into the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?